# iteration variable in fizzbuzz failing to print all correct answers?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I've been able to solve the fizzbuzz problem. I have a question regarding an alternative method.

Everything is great until I arrive at the number 10. In the console, the number 10 should print "buzz" but it prints the number 10 instead. After that it proceeds to work correctly. Also the "fizzbuzz" does not seem to work. If I change the fizzbuzz conditional to simply "if" then the code won't even run.

```js
for (let i = 1, j = 1; j <= 100, i <= 100; i++, j++) {

  if (j % 3 == 0) {
    j = "fizz";
  } else if (j % 5 == 0) {
    j = "buzz";
  } else if (j % 5 === 0 && j % 3 === 0) {

    j = "fizzbuzz";

  } else {
    j = i;
  }
  console.log(j)
}
```

What is the problem in this code, and why is the iteration variable not working for all of the numbers?

Comment: After setting `j` to one of the strings, the `j++` in the loop header will no longer work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congrats for your first answer.

Comment: Pointy, I am able to print all 100 numbers. The issue is that some numbers don't execute the code, like number 10. The rest work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `else if`'s. The line

```
} else if (j % 5 === 0 && j % 3 === 0) {
```

is located in an else statement and will never be executed if one of the other statements is true (either `j % 3 == 0` or `j % 5 == 0`) - i.e - it will never happen

Comment: I don't think this is the real problem, but it is an error. The real issue is that as soon as `j` is set to `"fizz"` it will become `NaN` when `j++` is evaluated in the loop header.

Answer (score 0):

Use a differebt variable instead of j

```
for (let i = 1, j = 1; j <= 100, i <= 100; i++, j++) {
   var res;
  if (j % 3 == 0) {
    res = "fizz";
  } else if (j % 5 == 0) {
    res = "buzz";
  } else if (j % 5 === 0 && j % 3 === 0) {

    res = "fizzbuzz";

  } else {
    res = i;
  }
  console.log(res)
}
```

You should also put the fizzbuzz condition first so that it gets reached when it is true(also you can eliminate the i loop) like

```
for (let j = 1; j <= 100, j++) {
      let res;
      if (j % 5 === 0 && j % 3 === 0) {

        res = "fizzbuzz";

      }
      else if (j % 3 == 0) {
        res = "fizz";
      } else if (j % 5 == 0) {
        res = "buzz";
      }else {
        res = j;
      }
      console.log(res)
    }
```

Comment: That works but it is a more conventional answer. I was looking for an alternative method, and trying to figure out why this code works up until it reaches the number 10, then goes back to working once more.

Comment: @JSMastery Your code doesn't run for 10 because j is set to fizz right before that because of 9. The rest works fine because when no conditions get matched you are setting j back to a valid number by doing j=i

Comment: and it goes back to working again because when the condition at 10 doesn't match j again gets set to a valid number in your else condition.

Comment: Any idea why the code breaks if I set the "fizzbuzz" simply to an "if" conditional instead of an "else if" ?

Comment: @JSMastery Yup, when the execution reaches 3 , j gets changed to fizz and then it goes on to check the changed if condition(fizzbuzz) and sees that the condition is false and hence executes the else block which sets j back to 3 which gets logged.